# How can i keep code that has Thread.Sleep() in it open when it finishes?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to make an application that print characters one by one like in old rps. I found out that i need to use Thread.Sleep to do that. I also want the code to stay open instead of closing. Is there any way to do that?

I used Console.Read, Console.ReadLine, and Console.ReadKey. but all of them stop printing what i want after the first character.

```
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sntnc = "Example";
        foreach (char chrctr in sntnc)
        {
            Console.Write(chrctr);
            Thread.Sleep(50)
```

;

I want the result to be an application that prints character individually and for it to stay open when it finished.

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the code? Specifically where you tried `Console.ReadKey()`?

Comment: It sounds like you need to put the `Console.ReadXXX` outside of the `foreach` loop. But as dvo mentioned, we're guessing at this point.

Comment: This is all the code. I forgot to mention i'm a beginner. Also i added it to the end with Console.Write and Thread.Sleep.

Comment: @avideTemporicidal see my answer. you are very close.

Comment: @dvo Just read you're answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. When you are inside the foreach loop, your code will keep running and keep your console window open. After the foreach loop, you can call `Console.ReadKey();` to keep the console open until a key is pressed. This code will print out the characters one by one with a 50 ms delay between each letter.

```
public static void Main()
{
    string sntnc = "Example";
    foreach (char chrctr in sntnc)
    {
        Console.Write(chrctr);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```